# Find references of property name in criteria hibernate java

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3.0 with Java 6 and Eclipse Juno.
I have a POJO named Teacher.java which is described as under:

**Teacher.java**

```
public class Teacher {
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Now, I have written a criteria with Restriction on userName in some class to fetch Objects of Teacher class with userName = 'test'.
There may be other criterias using userName.

My question is: Is there some way so that I can find all such Criterias in my application?

Comment: All such criteras in the sense ? What you are trying to mean it here ?

Comment: @TheUnlucky All the criteria written in the application that uses userName property of Teacher class.

Comment: Are you aware about the Entity Class , DAO classes as such ?

Comment: We aren't using Entity classes. DAO classes are there.